# Refactoring javascript callbacks - function out of namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters, callback

I have a Javascript function like so:

```
function a(par1) {
    fun.doSth(function(par2) {
        another.doSth(function() {
           //par1 is needed here
        })
    })
}
```

Now, it does work like this and I can access par1 in that second callback. But I want to refactor a bit and make the two anonymous functions named functions for readability

```
function a(par1) {
    fun.doSth(b)
}

function b(par2) {
    another.doSth(c)
}

function c() {
    //par1 is needed here
}
```

But now par1 isn't available anymore, I guess because c out of the scope of a? Is the only way of fixing this passing par1 through these functions as parameter?

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide par1 to `function c()` as an argument. There is no way of making it clean otherwise

Comment: Damn okay, thanks. Is it possible to pass a callback function with a "pre-filled" parameter? Like so:
    `
    function callback(a,b){}

    function a(par1) {
         call(callback(b=par1))
    } 
     
    function call(callback) {
         callback(a=4)
     }
`
Because if not, I think I have an idea what to implement in the next js update lol

Comment: sure it is. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind - section 'Partially applied functions'

Answer (score 2):

You can use `currying`:

```js
function doSomething1(cb1) {
    cb1(1);
}

function doSomething2(cb2) {
    cb2(2);
}

function a(par1) {
    doSomething1(b(par1))
}

function b(par1) {
    return function (par2) {
        doSomething2(c(par1))
    }
}

function c(par1) {
    return function c(arg) {
        console.log('arg: ', arg, 'par1: ', par1);
    }
}

console.log(a(0));
```